# How should we handle wifi and other connection type questions?

Tags: discussion

Just doing a quick scan and seemingly we have hundreds of "cannot connect" wifi and other type connection questions.

My question is simple... Should be be treating these as bug-reports and hence closed as "off-topic" with a comment to file a bug?

Or should we be trying to solve these issues and treating these as valid for this Q&A site?

I'm torn - these type of issues should be filed on launchpad otherwise the kernel devs won't have visibility.

But then again, I'm also thinking that they are valid questions for AU

Comment: I think most them are duplicates and did not check that out when asking a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think we should close these as bugs as a general rule; from reading them they can go either way.

There's a bunch of ones that are module blacklists, installing the wrong driver and needing to swap it out, or editing a config file in order to make it work. I think this is one of those areas where we can really improve the user-workaround experience.

Though if it's something like a crash report that needs to be submitted then in that case it should be a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend a lot on the usefulness of the answer and how much work will it be to help the users.

I do not think it is the same as asking something very specific that only affects a few users but I also feel a bit split about them. I am sure there are many many bug reports already that explain why chipset X drivers are not being correctly installed activated.

My suggestion is do what we have been doing until now, make a broad question / answer and make it the default go to for dupes. These questions support a huge quantity of users that without the help provided will be lost without a wireless connection.

Answer (score -1):

If there is a real intent to actually help rather than boosting some site metric, redirecting to support threads in ubuntu forums is more helpful than asking people to file bug reports on launchpad, for notorious issues like [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1022411) anyway.

Comment: My experience so far tells me that is not always the case, why else would a workaround from a few years back continue to be relevant and after numerous bug reports filed? Until something actually gets fixed, only workarounds are of any direct relevance to the user.

Comment: it's not really helpful to keep mentioning "boosting some site metric". That is clearly not **all** that we are doing. It is only fair that we ensure to put things where they really belong. If bugs are not taken care of correctly on launchpad, that is in all honesty not the problem of Ask Ubuntu, as much as we would want to help.